# How to download/implement a dependency in Artifactory

Tags: android, maven, artifactory

I have Artifactory Open Source installed on a server and upload an android AAR library by hand.

In the gradle file, I set up a configuration like this.

```
buildscript {
    
        dependencies { classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release" }
    
        repositories {
            maven {
                credentials {
                    username = artifactory_username
                    password = artifactory_password
                }
                url "https://.../artifactory/libs-release"
            }
        }
    }
    
    allprojects{
            apply plugin: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin
            artifactory {
                resolve {
                    contextUrl = "https://.../artifactory"
                    repoKey = 'libs-global'
                    username = artifactory_username
                    password = artifactory_password
                }
            }
        }
        
    buildscript {
       repositories {
            jcenter()
       }
    
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"
        }
       }
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
```

How can download or implement my AAR library in the android project?

**Example:**

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your URL in the build.gradle (project) file like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url("https://your-url.jfrog.com/more/path")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you just add your dependency in dependencies.